# How to get values of tbody element from the Table using the Table id and without giving tbody ID using javascript not Jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am looking for the elements inside the tbody of table without using the tbody Id or class. from below code i am looking for the values inside td for those who has tr classname tag.

```
<table id="tableId">
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
value
</tr>
<tr class="className">
<td>
value
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
value
</tr>
<tr class="className">
<td>
value
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use javascript querySelector  - document.querySelector('#tableId > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var tableId = document.getElementById('tableId');
var tBody = tableId.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var tableRow = tBody.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var t = 0; t < tableRow.length; t++){
    console.log(tableRow[t].innerHTML)
}
```

Comment: can you please look this question again i made some change. I am sorry for this. @Nisar